# add_rewrite_endpoint returns 404 on archives

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, archives, endpoints

My endpoint works on all kind of single pages and homepage, but it returns 404 in archive pages, either categories or custom taxonomes. I have reflushed rewrites but I don't get it work. This is my code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_amp_custom_endpoints', 1000 );

function add_amp_custom_endpoints() {
    define( 'AMP_QUERY_VAR', apply_filters( 'amp_query_var', 'amp' ) );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'amp', EP_ALL );
}
```

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Comment: Rewrite endpoints should added on the init action.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work either. I checked the rewrite rules list and there'n no any amp rewrite rule. If I replace EP_CATEGORIES by EP_PERMALINK, all post_types got my custom endpoint, but categories don't.